# State space model with input derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

How to include the derivative of an input directly into a state space model?

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{\mathbf x}(t) &= \mathbf A \mathbf x(t) + \mathbf B \dot{\mathbf u}(t) \\
\mathbf y(t) &= \mathbf C \mathbf x(t)
\end{aligned}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

By definining $\mathbf z(t) \triangleq \mathbf x(t) - \mathbf B \mathbf u(t) $ we can write:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{\mathbf z}(t) &= \mathbf A \mathbf z(t) + \mathbf A\mathbf B \mathbf u(t) \\
\mathbf y(t) &= \mathbf C \mathbf z(t) + \mathbf C \mathbf B \mathbf u(t)
\end{aligned}\tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{equation}

where the input now enterse the system directly.
Systems $\eqref{eq1}$ and $\eqref{eq2}$ appear to deliver the same results when $\mathbf x(0) = \mathbf B\mathbf u(0)$ for $\eqref{eq1}$ and $\mathbf z(0) = 0$ for $\eqref{eq2}$.

Is this a general result?

Comment: I assume you meant $z(0)=0$ for $(2)$? And your question is if the coordinate transformation you used holds for all possible choices of the (appropiately sized) matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen 1. I corrected the question. 2. Yes - I want to know if this is a general property. I suspect it is because it can be derived by $\exp(\mathbf At) * \mathbf B \dot{\mathbf u}(t) = \mathbf A\exp(\mathbf At) * \mathbf B \mathbf u(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a general result for also independent $x(0)$ and $u(0)$. Consider the solution of the first system:
$$\begin{align}
x(t) &= e^{At} x(0) + \int_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)} B \dot{u} (\tau) d \tau \\
&= e^{At} x(0) + e^{At} \left[ \left. e^{-A \tau}B u(\tau) \right|_{\tau=0}^t + \int_0^t e^{-A\tau} A B u(\tau) d\tau \right] \\
x(t) - Bu(t) &= e^{At} \left[ x(0) - B u(0) \right] + \int_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)} A B u(\tau) d\tau
\end{align}$$
which is the solution to the second equation for $z(0) = x(0) - B u(0)$. It is easy to show that $y(t)$ are also the same for both equations.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

[image]

I will type it later. For more info see Modern Control Engineering by Ogata and State variables for engineers by DeRusso et al. They provide full details. The example above from Ogata.

Comment: I tried the canonical realizations with a second-order system with one input and one output. However, MATLAB's documentation states that the companion form of the state matrix is easily numerically ill-conditioned. Hence, I used the convolution property $f'(x)*g(x) = f(x) * g'(x) $.